# Reading a date string with a different time zone in javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone, datejs

I have a datestring, pulled from an external source, that looks like this:

```
9/25/2011 4:38:40 PM
```

That source in the the `PDT` timezone.

I'd like to create a UTC date out of that information, using [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). I'm using this code to parse it at present:

```
var dateString = '9/25/2011 4:38:40 PM';
var d = Date.parseExact('9/25/2011 4:38:40 PM', 'M/d/yyyy H:m:s tt');
```

While this does load the date, it does so as if it were in my timezone. How can I tell date.js that the date I'm telling it is from a different time zone?

Comment: Please note that there is no standard for timezone abbreviations or acronyms and many are ambiguous (EST is used for 3 different timezones). It is far better to use the actual offset (per ECMA-262 15.9.1.15).

Comment: @RobG: I completely forgot about that - good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use timezone format specifier...

```
var dateString = '9/25/2011 4:38:40 PM EST';
var d = Date.parseExact(dateString, 'M/d/yyyy H:m:s tt Z');
```

Comment: I don't actually have control of the string. Should I just append the time zone on the end before parsing it?

Comment: @Eric, which string? The dateString or the format string? If dateString then you could append the timezone, assuming you know the value in all the cases.

Comment: dateString. Although as @RobG says, I should use an offset rather than a 3 letter code.

Answer (score 1):

putting an e in a date format will signify the timezone.  I haven't tested this, but:

```
Date.parseExact(dateString + " PDT", "M/d/yyyy H:m:s tt e")
```

Does not account for daylight savings time shifts (PST instead of PDT), but you get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?:

```
var dateString = '9/25/2011 4:38:40 PM';

var date = Date.parseExact(dateString, format);
var utc_date = new Date(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000))
```